# Появление модального окна после перезагрузки страницы в ASP

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Открываю страницу жму на кнопку, выскакивает модальное окно, вот так выглядит фронтэнд

```
contacts.aspx.cs

 public partial class contacts : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                BindTable();

            }
        }
        protected void BindTable()
        {
            using (fenixcontactEntities db = new fenixcontactEntities())
            {

                var result = from row in db.people select row;
                //Сортировка списка 
                var sortList = result.OrderBy(x => x.lastname).ToList();

                ReapeterContacts.DataSource = sortList;
                ReapeterContacts.DataBind();

            }
        }
        protected void ShowContact_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {

            int rowInd = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            using (fenixcontactEntities db = new fenixcontactEntities())
            {

                var showPerson = db.people.First(p => p.id == rowInd);


                string img = String.Concat("Img/persons/", showPerson.img2, ".jpg");
                ContactImgPics.ImageUrl = img;
                FioLB.Text = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", showPerson.lastname, showPerson.firstname, showPerson.middlename);
                ModalLBCompany.Text = showPerson.company;
                ModalLBPosition.Text = showPerson.position;

                ModalLBDepartament.Text = showPerson.departments;
                ModalLBTelephone.Text = showPerson.work_phone1;
                ModalLBEmail.Text = showPerson.email1;
                ModalLBAddress.Text = showPerson.address;
                ModalLBirthday.Text = String.Format("{0:m}", showPerson.birthday);
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", true);

            }


        }
```

После этого если я обновляю страницу, у меня снова выскакивает окно с последним открытым модальным окном. Не могу понять, почему так происходит.

Выглядит это так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ставлю брейкпоинт и происходит следующее, после Page_Load ->BindTable тут я нажимаю на модальное окно идет  вызов ShowContact_Command Потом обновляю страницу и снова мигом вызывается ShowContact_Command. Не могу понять откуда он берет все это? Где я не прав?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Извините, конечно, но это совсем уже не современный и не правильный подход. Следует использовать AJAX, ибо перезагружать всю страницу ради того, чтобы открыть всплывающее окно с десятой долей общего контента - это как минимум не экономно как для клиента, так и для сервера.

А ошибка возникает потому, что кнопка обновления повторяет последний запрос. Учитывая, что последний запрос просил зарегистрировать старт-ап скрипт с открытием окна, вы получаете цикличность. Искренне советую вам переписать это дело с использованием AJAX и WCF\WebService\MVC и иже с ними.

Answer (score 0):

Как уже заметил @v319 проблема в том, что браузер получает задачу повторить последний запрос. По факту происходит не сколько перезагрузка страницы, сколько повторная отправка запроса.

Я думаю, что если не переписывать, а использовать более мягкий подход, то можно либо автоматически обновлять вывод информации на страницу либо сделать это через специальную кнопку.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         BindTable();
    }
```

и в код поставить

```
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```